# "TypeError: WebSocket.Server is not a constructor" when trying to make an express & ws server

Tags: node.js, express, ws

I am trying to make an express and websockets server, and I have two files: `http-server.js` and `ws-server.js`. I get the error `TypeError: WebSocket.Server is not a constructor` when I try to run `node ws-server.js`

I got this error in my project, so I tried making a clean project, but the error persists. I've tried clearing node's cache, checking node version and reinstalling ws.

http-server.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const port = 3000;
const ip = '0.0.0.0';

export const app = express();
```

ws-server.js:

```
import http from 'http'
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import { app } from './http-server.js'

const port = 3000;
const ip = '0.0.0.0';

const server = http.createServer();

const wss = new WebSocket.Server();

server.on('request', app);
server.listen(port, ip, () => { console.log(`Serving on ${ip}:${port}`) });
```